# Xcode git authentication fails when enforce ssh in global git config

Tags: xcode, git, github

I have enforced using ssh in git cli in my `.gitconfig` by adding following snipper:

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

However, this breaks Xcode and it fails to fetch any Github links with the following error:

> github.com: Authentication failed because no credentials were provided.

It doesn't matter whether I choose SSH or HTTP in Xcode settings as well. The Xcode is setup with a personal token and the same ssh key that's used by CLI.

I'm trying to see if there's any way to enforce ssh while not breaking whatever Xcode is going to fetch repos.

Comment: Have you solved this?  I have the same issue

Comment: Nope, it's still an issue, need to submit a ticket to Apple

Comment: Thank you  I finally know where this error came from! I'd like a real fix but I disabled this gitconfig line as a temporary workaround.